# Create an ISO image from video files and write it to USB drive

Tags: linux, usb, video, iso-image

I need to copy 10 videos to 40 USB drives. But a simple copy-paste will take longer than my life, so I tried to make an image file from the videos and write them to multiple USB drives using `gnome-image-writer`.

When I write the image file (`.iso`) to the USB using any tool such MultiWriter, SUSE Image Studio, Etcher, etc. everything seems to work properly on my Linux and macOS systems, but when I connect the USB drive to a Windows OS it just displays the message:

> You need to format your device in order to use it

so I can not use the USB drive on Windows systems.

I used many programs to create ISO images from the files.

When I do the same, but with an OS `.iso` file (Ubuntu, Windows, etc.), the `.iso` file is written properly and Windows recognizes it without problems. It is not the same when I try to make an image of my video files and write them onto the USB. I also formatted the USB in the beginning as FAT32, NTFS, ExFat, etc. trying to find the problem.

Edit: I want to add that when I do the image with the Mac Disk-utility as a cd/dvd master and create the .cdr file and later I convert to an .iso and use the gnome-multiwriter to write it in the differents usb everything works perfectly and Windows recognize the usb without any problem.

Comment: It'd probably help if you showed the exact steps you took using `gnome-image-writer`. You can [edit] your question and add that.

Comment: You may use a USB hub to fast that process. Many PC has 5 or 6 USB port, use those if have.

Comment: I am using a hub already, the ports are not the problem.

Comment: With Gnome-writer I just select the iso and press start copy, the software is simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

ISO images contain formatting for optical media that is not appropriate for flash media (which uses the same formatting as a hard drive). Specifically, ISOs use the Joliet file system same as CDs and DVDs do while most flash media uses FAT32 or exFAT (or, rarely, NTFS). I can only assume the tools you are using in Windows are silently converting the files back and forth while the Linux tools are not.

If you want to use image files to stamp out your flash devices filesystems I'd suggest using an actual hdd/ssd imaging/cloning tool like [dd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/disk_cloning). Remember, flash media are functionally indistinguishable from HDDs and SSDs at the user level, so what works for one should work for the other (mostly). So put the files you want on that first USB drive then image it with dd, then put your new USB drive and clone the image to the new drive with dd. You could even, potentially, do multiple USB drives at once, depending on the available bandwidth on your USB bus (usually plenty).

Comment: So, why using the mac disk-utility to create an .cdr image and later convert it to an .iso file it works properly?

Comment: Because of differences in the tools. It's still the wrong tool for the job and that it "works" is what's actually in error. If those work fine and you're satisfied with the results you're free to do it that way all you want. That you're here asking for help implies that's not the case. I've given you an alternative option. You're free to use it or not. If there's something specific you dislike about the option I've given (like maybe you don't want to fool with the command line) there are other tools that do similar and all you have to do it ask.